# How do I add a button on side of a listview

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want to have a button on the right side of a listview
I tried putting it in a row but it will cause an error
I tried putting it in a container to have a size and put the container inside of a row but still error

How do I do this
newbie here

```
Row(
..
  children:[
    ListView(
    items...
    ),
    FlatButton(...)

  ]
)
```

something like this?

Comment: post your code..

Comment: I don't have one because I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Row(
..
children:[
]
)

Comment: Do you want to add a button for every list-item?

Comment: No It is a horizontal listview with a container in it, I want the button outside of the listview at the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,
  children:[
    Expanded(
    child:ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children:[
      Text('12345 '),
      Text('12345 '),
      Text('12345 '),
      Text('12345 '),
      Text('12345 '),
    ]
    ),),
    FlatButton(child:Text('button')),
  ]
),
```

Just wrap your list in expanded and some alignment in row to properly align it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Container(
      width: 300,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          Text("hey"),
          Text("hey"),
          Text("hey"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    ElevatedButton(
      child: Text("hey"),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ],
)
```

You can not put ListView in a Row because ListView needs a height.

You can customize the code for your needs.

Edit: You can change the scroll direction using `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` .

Comment: So this does not work, my listview is horizontal and I want the button on the right side of the listview(outside).